# SharePoint 2010 User Profile Sync - Remove Disabled Users

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2010, user-profile

I have SharePoint 2010 set up to sync active directory users and it is working great. I am getting disabled users in the sync though. I have tried what all the blogs say, filter on

userAccountControl bit on equals 2

but to no avail, the disabled users are still syncing. I am at a loss on where to look next. My last resort would be to create a ou/folder in AD and move disabled users there and remove that from the sync connector, but I don't really want to go there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the filter works, but only before a user is imported and a profile created. If you do an import of all users, then put the filter up, it doesn't work. I had to remove the disabled users that were imported before I had a filter manually. Any users after that become disabled then seem to get removed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try this?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brporter/archive/2010/02/20/excluding-disabled-user-accounts-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

I got a little confused by whether you should use ==2 or !=2....

HTH.

Regards..

Roger Williams
Franklin Laboratory